# Google Chrome min-height inheriting issue

Tags: css, google-chrome, flexbox, tailwind-css

I have a simple page with a nested div containing content and button below it, that seems look fine on Safari and Firefox but was having issues on Chrome with the vertical alignment - two elements superimpose on each other due to the `min-h-inherit` not working(i.e inheriting) as expected.

HTML:

```
<div id="cont" class="flex flex-col min-h-inherit">
 <div>
   ...
 </div> 
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

#cont{
  position: relative;
}
```

A workaround was to specifically include `h-screen` in the `cont` div but this seems to break the functionality on Safari, by adding a scroll bar to the page and increasing the relative height between the `div`'s.

However, this issue seemed to resolve a bit when adding `display: flex` to the `body`, however this seems to break in certain screen sizes:

```
body {
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
  display: flex;
}
```

Spent a lot of time trying to get the inheritance to work as expected by referring to existing answers regarding this webkit bug/functionality. Don't understand what the best way to resolve this is.

New to CSS so would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on this. Thanks!